# What is the size of Windows Phone 8.1 update?

Tags: 8.1, lumia-520

I cannot find the answer to how much data will this update consume? Some forums mentioned that I should have almost 1.5 GB of free space in my phone before I update it, but there is no information as to what is the file size of this update.

Please advice.

### Update

From the comments and answers its apparent that I didn't place the question correctly. While I am glad that I got to know the total disk space this update is going to take, I originally intended to ask the bandwidth consumption this update is going to take. I.E. how much Wi-Fi Data I need to successfully download this update.

Thanks.

Comment: the exact size varies a bit depending on the device and network branding.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/5214/106

Comment: @Rowland I think there is some ambiguity in the question. I am actually asking the amount of Wi-Fi Data consumption or the bandwidth consumption for this update. As far as I can remember the black update was a 450MB download which required almost 1GB to install successfully. So I guess the cyan update must be close to around a 500MB download.

Answer (score 2):

I think the download is around 1.5 GB in size. I downloaded the update using *Nokia Software Recovery Tool* and the download bar in it showed 1.5 GB.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the lumia black update is 250MB while windows 8.1 Cyan is 500MB and windows 8.1 update(denim) is 250MB which means you atleast need 1.1GB bandwidth and abt 2GB free space

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Storage Sense](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-ca/how-to/wp8/settings-and-personalization/storage-on-my-phone) (which is new with Windows Phone 8.1), my "system" uses 3.40 GB.

I'm in Canada and Cortana was not included for us in this version, so it may add somewhat to the total.

So you may want a bit more free space before than 1.5 GB before you attempt the update.

To help you clear space on Windows Phone 8.0, see if you can still get the [Lumia Storage Check beta](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/lumia-storage-check-beta/c2adc981-83c2-4f19-8161-67149e44214c) app from the Windows store. They ended the beta but it still might be available for Windows Phone 8.0 users.

Comment: Thanks. That did come in handy. Please take a look at the updated question.

Comment: This does not answer the question (ie. what is the size of the 8.1 update)

Comment: @NeilTurner - the poster updated his question since I answered it. See his comment just before yours. It makes no sense for me to attempt to update my answer since I don't know the answer to his new question.

Answer (score -1):

it only needs 500Mb but you should have free space more than 1.5GB

Comment: Can you clarify? If it only needs 500 MB, why should one have more than 1.5 GB free space?