# Windows Phone "System" size

Tags: lumia

Storage Sense reports that the "System" is using 5.88 GB. That seems large on a phone with 7.2 GB total. Storage check says the "System" is only 1.9? 
Also Other is listed as 3.9 GB.

I have a Lumia 521.

Is this normal?

Comment: The size of "Other" makes sense. Are you running WP 8 or 8.1? Also, the difference in the reports is because it's Nokia's app vs Microsoft's app. Microsoft's (Storage Sense) is generally more accurate.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/5586/106

Comment: It is running Windows Phone 8.1. The "System" taking 5.88 GB on a 7.2 GB phone is my big question. Thanks

Comment: I have a 1020 on which System uses 3.73 GB and an Icon on which System uses 4.25 GB. So obviously it can vary. And (compared to 4.25 GB) 5.88 GB seems semi-reasonable. I guess that's why it comes with a microSD slot.

Answer (score 1):

System being 5.88GB sounds about right, that's approximately what my Lumia 930 is saying (well, 5.13GB). I reckon this could be because it is sharing large amounts of the core functionality with Windows 8.1. The size of Other in the Storage Check app is probably just system files but for some reason the app is recognising them as other files instead (add 3.9 and 1.9 and you get 5.8, approximately the same size as the size of System in the Storage Sense app).